# Change the FAQ link to the Meta FAQ to go to the FAQ Index page, and not search results?

Tags: feature-request, faq-update-request

The [bottom of our FAQ](https://stackoverflow.com/faq#what-about) says:

> ## What if I need more help?
>
> If you’re looking for excruciating detail, our [meta-discussion
>   site](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/) hosts a section of constantly evolving [**frequently asked
>   questions**](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/faq) that document everything about the site.

The link to the "constantly evolving frequently asked questions" goes to [a confusing list of site-specific meta questions tagged [faq]](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/faq), which is sorted in no particular order, and not very helpful to users seeking more information about the site.

[image: Questions Tagged FAQ]

It would be better if that link went to the [Community FAQ Index](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7931/faq-for-stack-exchange-sites), which is much more understandable and easier to read and browse through than an unsorted list of questions.

[image: Community FAQ Index]

Can we change the /faq link for the MSO Community FAQ so it goes to the [MSO Community FAQ Index](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7931/faq-for-stack-exchange-sites) instead of displaying a list of MSO questions tagged [faq]?

**Edit**

As [Ben Brocka pointed out](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/171894/change-the-faq-link-to-the-meta-faq-to-go-to-the-faq-index-page-and-not-search#comment509372_171894), this link is site-specific and goes to the meta site specific to the SE site, and not to MSO. I think it should go to the MSO Community FAQ Index instead since the meta-FAQ is fairly incomplete on most smaller sites.

Something like:

> ## What if I need more help?
>
> If you’re looking for more details, visit our constantly evolving
>   [Community FAQ](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7931/faq-for-stack-exchange-sites) that documents everything about our Q&A sites, or
>   browse our [meta-discussion site](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/) to get answers to other
>   questions about this site.

Comment: This change makes sense on Meta but other sites dont' have the pre-built FAQ; just the FAQ tag. Pretty sure that's why it does that.

Comment: @BenBrocka Thanks for pointing that out. That portion of the FAQ is the same for all SE sites, and I think it should point to the MSO Community FAQ instead of the site-specific list of meta-questions tagged [faq] since I'm fairly sure the MSO community FAQ isn't replicated on other SE meta sites.

Comment: On Drupal Answers, I created some CW tagged [tag:faq]. Some of the questions repeats what said in other questions on this site, but some questions are specific for the site.